# How to detect letter “H” from any angle

Tags: python, opencv, detection, contour

I'm struggling to detect a specific shape in openCV using python. The specific shape is the letter "H".

I have considered multiple methods of doing this. Template matching and OCR will not work at any angle so I'm thinking of using canny edge detection.
Could any of you please provide some guidance on how to move forward from here. After applying the Canny filter, how do I check that the letter "H" is present?

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
binary = cv2.erode(gray, None, iterations=2)
median_filter = cv2.medianBlur(binary, 3)
edges = cv2.Canny(median_filter, 120, 180)

bin, contours, _hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    cnt_len = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    cnt = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02 * cnt_len, True)

cv2.imshow("crop", binary)
cv2.imshow("Frame", edges)
cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

if key == ord("q"):
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This page might be useful: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html

Comment: I have tried this before but I'm get no output from it.

Comment: You sure? It's not template matching, it's feature matching. It's pretty good at finding simple patterns. Describe the limitations of your task in more details (is H the same font, color etc, image quality and lighting, is it just scaled/rotated or full perspective) and i'll try to throw together an example in a couple days if that's not too late for you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (but slow) solution would be to run template matching or OCR at many rotated versions of the images. OCR methods usually have at least some small rotation tolerance, so you may not need that many. If computational complexity is not an issue, this is what I'd do, as it is very robust.

If you need a fast solution, you can try using a heuristic to find the rotation first. For example, you could find the dominant edge directions. For an H, the dominant edge direction would be that of the vertical bars on the sides of the H. Using that direction you can correct the rotation and use OCR or template matching. This will of course not work for arbitrary patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Hough Transformation after using Canny Edge. You are going to get always two parallel lines and one perpendicular to both straight lines without having to look for the angle. Thats already implemented in OpenCV(Probabilistic Line Transformation). After that you need to check the output lines for parallelity and last the perpendicular line, where all lines should be connected.
[Link](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html)

```
// runs detection
HoughLinesP(image, linesP, rho, (CV_PI / 180)*theta, threshold, minLineLength, maxLineGap); 
    }
//Draw lines
for (int i = 0; i < linesP.size(); i++)
    {
        Vec4i l = linesP[i];
        line(image, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(255, 255, 255), 3, LINE_AA);
    }
//continue here
```

Comment: could you please give me more info how to get parallel line or write some examples for me? thanks

Comment: You will get lines as a result from HoughLinesP. By iteraring through all lines you can see if the distances remain the same from the starting point of the line and also the end point of the line. Example lines a and b. Distance a1 = b1 and a2 = b2. If its the same distance you should have found your „I I“ from „H“. double xDiff = a.x - b.x;
    double yDiff = a.y - b.y;

    std::sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff));

Comment: Now you have to search the interesection points to find the „-„ from „H“. Look into this: http://answers.opencv.org/question/9511/how-to-find-the-intersection-point-of-two-lines/